# How to install the IEDriverServer_x64_.. to work with Internet Explorer in webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have downloaded the IE Driver server for 64 bit, and unzipped the same and kept that on my desktop.

Along with that I have did the below modification in my Internet Explorer:

1) Changed browser zoom level to 100%

2) Checked the "Enable Protection Mode" check box for all zones.

3) Kept all the zone level wit "Medium-High".

Now i am writing the below code in eclipse:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    File file=new File("C:\\Users\\RASH\\Desktop\\Selenium\\Selenium jars\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    System.setProperty("Webdriver.ie.driver",file.getAbsolutePath());
    WebDriver driver= new Internet Explorer Driver();
    driver.get("http://google.com");
}
```

but while running i am getting an exception as :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property; for more information, see http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list
```

Answer (score 0):

The location of the executable must be in your path.

To add a folder to your path, navigate to  `Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables`, find the variable named `Path` in the bottom window, select it and click `Edit`.

Then add a semi-colon followed by the directory you wish to add to your path. For example, append `;C:\Drivers\` to the existing path, where the IEDriver is in the `C:\Drivers\` directory.

Comment: But after doing the path setting, it is running fine. But in the console of eclipse I m getting exception in thread "main" as java.long.illegalStateException.